# How do I create an invitation to a class using the invitations.create() method?

Tags: google-classroom

I'm using the Google Classroom API with Python, and am trying to invite a student to a course, using the `invitations.create()` method. However, I keep getting a "404 requested entity not found" error, and I'm unsure what's causing it.

```
service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)
info = {
  "userId": "zariftwitters@gmail.com",
  "courseId": "117906298438634973718",
  "role": "STUDENT"
}
i = service.invitations().create(body=info).execute()
```

Error message:

> Http Error 404 when requesting
>   https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/invitations?alt=json returned
>   "Requested entity was not found."

Answer (score 1):

### Most likely it means that the course Id is incorrect

- The course Id should contain 11 numbers.
- You can list all courses and their Ids with the method [courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list), the easiest way to do it would be with the `Try this API`.